# Comparing one element from a list to ALL elements of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that contains various sequences of letters.

```
sequences = ['AAGTAAA', 'AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT', 'TTTTCCC', 'AATTCGC', 'CGCTCCC']
```

I want to see if the last 3 letter of each sequence in that list matches the first 3 letters of all the other sequences. If that happens, I want to know the indexes of these two sequences.

I'm basically trying to produce an adjacency list. Below is an example of an input:

```
>Sample_0
AAGTAAA
>Sample_1
AAATGAT
>Sample_2
AAAGTTT
>Sample_3
TTTTCCC
>Sample_4
AATTCGC
>Sample_5
CGCTCCC
```

And the output:

```
>Sample_0 >Sample_1
>Sample_0 >Sample_2
>Sample_2 >Sample_3
>Sample_4 >Sample_5
```

Now, I tried to make two different lists that contain all the prefixes and all the suffixes but I don't know if this can help and how to use this to solve my problem.

```
file = open("rosalind_grph2.txt", "r")

gene_names, sequences, = [], []
seq = ""

for line in file:
    if line[0] == ">":
        gene_names.append(line.strip())
        if seq == "":
            continue
        sequences.append(seq)
        seq = ""
    if line[0] in "ATCG":
        seq = seq + line.strip()
sequences.append(seq)

#So far I put all I needed into a list

prefix = [i[0:3] for i in sequences]
suffix = [i[len(i)-3:] for i in sequences]

#Now, all suffixes and prefixes are in lists as well
#but what now?  

print(suffix)
print(prefix)
print(sequences)
file.close
```

Comment: So if you have two sequences with different 3 letters, there is no sequence that matches all, right?

Comment: Could you please (a) fix the syntax error in your code and (b) provide some toy examples with provided input and expected output? Right now it is not clear from your wording what you would like to do.

Comment: @DanielMesejo Yes, correct

Comment: @norok2 Edited, done!

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand how to interpret your notations for the input and output. Could you please use Python for that as well? If I understood correctly, your *input* is just the same as `sequences`, and your output is something that tells you which element of `sequences` is related to which other. Is that correct?

Comment: @norok2 Yes, that's right. Each element in  `sequence` is a line of letters made up of ATGC. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, this code enumerates over the list twice. It is comparing the last 3 letters of first element with the first 3 letters of the second element and prints the indices of the elements if there is a match. Please give feedback/clarify if this is not what you are looking for. This is O(n^2) and can likely be sped up if you take a initial pass and store indices in a structure like a dictionary.

```
for index1, sequence1 in enumerate(sequences):
    for index2, sequence2 in enumerate(sequences):
        if index1 != index2:
            if sequence1[-3:] == sequence2[0:3]:
                print(sequence1[-3:], index1, sequence2[0:3], index2)
```

Comment: Thank you. This actually works and makes sense in my head. However, if I use the example in the question, it only matches "AAA". There are still "TTT" and "CGC" to match. Also, I'm comparing the last 3 letters of EACH element with the first 3 letters of the ALL elements.

Comment: There is actually a *bug* in this code. `enumerate(sequences)` here returns a generator that will yield both the index and the element of an iterable. But it will do this only once. This means that the two `for` are impinging on the same generator. You would need to use `enumerate(sequences)` twice instead. Also, the double `if` is redundant, use `and` to combine the two conditions in a single `if`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you would like to do is to *connect* different element of `sequences`, where the connection is that beginning of the string matches the end of the other string.

One way of doing this, using a `dict` is by using the following function `match_head_tail()`:

```
def match_head_tail(items, length=3):
    result = {}
    for x in items:
        v = [y for y in items if y[:length] == x[-length:]]
        if v:
            result[x] = v
    return result
```

```
sequences = ['AAGTAAA', 'AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT', 'TTTTCCC', 'AATTCGC', 'CGCTCCC']

print(match_head_tail(sequences))
# {'AAGTAAA': ['AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT'], 'AAAGTTT': ['TTTTCCC'], 'AATTCGC': ['CGCTCCC']}
```

If you want to include also sequences for which there is no match you could use the following function `match_head_tail_all()`:

```
def match_head_tail_all( items, length=3):
    return {x: [y for y in items if y[:length] == x[-length:]] for x in items}
```

```
sequences = ['AAGTAAA', 'AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT', 'TTTTCCC', 'AATTCGC', 'CGCTCCC']

print(match_head_tail_all(sequences))
# {'AAGTAAA': ['AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT'], 'AAATGAT': [], 'AAAGTTT': ['TTTTCCC'], 'TTTTCCC': [], 'AATTCGC': ['CGCTCCC'], 'CGCTCCC': []}
```

---

## EDIT 1

If you actually want indexes, please combine the above with `enumerate()` to get them, e.g.:

```
def match_head_tail_all_indexes( items, length=3):
    return {
        i: [j for j, y in enumerate(items) if y[:length] == x[-length:]]
        for i, x in enumerate(items)}


sequences = ['AAGTAAA', 'AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT', 'TTTTCCC', 'AATTCGC', 'CGCTCCC']

print(match_head_tail_all_indexes(sequences))
# {0: [1, 2], 1: [], 2: [3], 3: [], 4: [5], 5: []}
```

---

## EDIT 2

If your input contains many sequences with the same ending, you may want to consider implementing some caching mechanism for improved computational efficiency (at the expenses of memory efficiency), e.g.:

```
def match_head_tail_cached(items, length=3, caching=True):
    result = {}
    if caching:
        cached = {}
    for x in items:
        if caching and x[-length:] in cached:
            v = cached[x[-length:]]
        else:
            v = [y for y in items if y[:length] == x[-length:]]    
        if v:
            result[x] = v
    return result


sequences = ['AAGTAAA', 'AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT', 'TTTTCCC', 'AATTCGC', 'CGCTCCC']

print(match_head_tail_cached(sequences))
# {'AAGTAAA': ['AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT'], 'AAAGTTT': ['TTTTCCC'], 'AATTCGC': ['CGCTCCC']}
```

---

## EDIT 3

All this could also implemented with `list` only, e.g.:

```
def match_head_tail_list(items, length=3):
    result = []
    for x in items:
        v = [y for y in items if y[:length] == x[-length:]]
        if v:
            result.append([x, v])
    return result


sequences = ['AAGTAAA', 'AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT', 'TTTTCCC', 'AATTCGC', 'CGCTCCC']

print(match_head_tail_list(sequences))
# [['AAGTAAA', ['AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT']], ['AAAGTTT', ['TTTTCCC']], ['AATTCGC', ['CGCTCCC']]]
```

and even have less nesting:

```
def match_head_tail_flat(items, length=3):
    result = []
    for x in items:
        for y in items:
            if y[:length] == x[-length:]:
                result.append([x, y])
    return result


sequences = ['AAGTAAA', 'AAATGAT', 'AAAGTTT', 'TTTTCCC', 'AATTCGC', 'CGCTCCC']

print(match_head_tail_flat(sequences))
# [['AAGTAAA', 'AAATGAT'], ['AAGTAAA', 'AAAGTTT'], ['AAAGTTT', 'TTTTCCC'], ['AATTCGC', 'CGCTCCC']]
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, I thought that using a dictionary would be helpful for my issue. However I barely used them so far so I'm a bit rusty, I always sticked to lists. I will have to do a bit of revision on dictionaries, thanks!! Plus, I didn't think to use such complex list comprehensions; you never stop learning :)

Comment: @Axelio see edits. Basically both `dict` and the additional container nesting, while reasonable, are quite optional and you can do without. In general, a `dict` will lead to a more efficient and with simpler syntax method of accessing data using a non-numeric *value*. The container nesting will lead to more efficient memory usage for 1-to-many relations, because the "1" will appear only once.